# How can I display unique names in Excel?

Tags: excel, duplicates, excel-formula

Given the following table on sheet one:

```
Name
-------
Alan
Barb
Corey
Barb
Alan
Daniel
Alan
```

How can I generate the following table on sheet two?

```
Name
-------
Alan
Barb
Corey
Daniel
```

I cannot leave empty rows like this:

```
Name
-------
Alan
Barb
Corey


Daniel
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a formulaic approach that is not version-dependent. See [Oscar's Site](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/03/30/how-to-extract-a-unique-list-and-the-duplicates-in-excel-from-one-column/).

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you have Excel 2007 or later.

Copy the entire list, duplicates and all, to Sheet 2.

Then go to the Data tab. In the Data tools section there is a large button called "Remove Duplicates." It will do just that.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to do it formulaically.

If you just need a one-time copy, though, [this article](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/msoffice/generate-a-list-of-unique-entries-in-an-excel-column/637) explains how to do it.